# Laravel - One CMS / multiple sites

Tags: php, laravel

## Laravel Folder Structure

I developed a CMS with laravel which I want to use for multiple websites. My goal is to have a single place to develop my CMS further and don't have old "CMS code" in older websites.

The problem is that I dont know how to structure my laravel folder structure. 
This is what I have in mind:

- --cms

  - --website-1
  - --website-2
  - --website-3

each website must have it's own
- public folder
- .env file (or config for database and other website specific settings)
- routes 
- resources(views, assets)
- controller('s)
- lang files
- etc.

## Development Environment

In development I want to use the website's domain(website-1.test) as indicator what website folder should be used.

## Production Environment & Git

I use forge to deploy my websites. My idea is to have a git repository for the CMS and a git repository for each of the websites. In the websites repositories I only push the website folder. In the CMS repository the whole project is saved but all the website folders are .gitignored.

So for the production server i had this folder structure in mind:

- CMS (git repo)

  - website (git repo)

When updating the front of a website I push the website repo, if I want to update the CMS I push the CMS repo.

## Conclusion

Bare in mind that these are my first thoughts and I am aware that my ideas might not be possible at all. I'm looking for advice and suggestions for my situation. If it can be achieved in another way or a better way I'd be glad to receive advice on that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Laravel supports domain mapping, see https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing. Just point the domains to the same instance and use your routes properly

Answer (score 0):

Ok .
It is not posible in same project.
But you can make subdirectories for you domain name.
It will become website-one.yoursitename.com.
And this each subdirectory will have its own files.
Thats all you need to accomplish what you want.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I have two initial ideas of how what you are asking for potentially could be achieved:

- **API**

  Make one repo for backend creation through CMS in witch you can create multiple APIs for various sites. Then make a front-end repo for each site that calls the corresponding API.

  https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources
- **Package**

  You could make a composer package for your cms code and then pull that package in to each of your website project

  https://blog.jgrossi.com/2013/creating-your-first-composer-packagist-package/