# Laravel Serves As Backend To Multiple Remote Customers Databases

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm planning to start a new project with Laravel, but there is something about that, which is a brand-new concept for me. I know Laravel can serve as backend to multiple SPA via API, but I have no idea how should I approach to my project.

Let's say I'll build an e-commerce app and sell it to multiple customers. I will offer two options:

1. The expensive one: All source code will be shipped to my customers and give them technical support, updates, new features, etc.
2. The cheap one: The customers will buy the rights of using my code which will be stored on my server. But I don't want to overtake the responsibility of data security. That's why in this option, my customers should have their own databases on their own servers. This is where my problem begins...

I prefer the 2nd option to deal with updates, bugs fixes, add/remove features and everything in one repository. I also think it's a better idea not to publish source code because of business and security reasons.

But I have no idea how can it be done. Is it even possible to succeed it? What about the performance issues? Basically, I'm clueless about that concept. Any kind of idea, article, video will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some options I have found searching the internet:

1. https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/fdslmi/how_to_host_multiple_websites_of_the_same_code/
2. [Laravel - One CMS / multiple sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57195573/laravel-one-cms-multiple-sites)

I hope that you find what you need!

Comment: Thanks. This was what I need to know.